# More often than not, can we use it in different contexts, changing the fixed expression a bit?

Tags: phrase-usage, idioms

He was injured in **more places than not**.

I have heard a lot of people use "more often than not", which upon looking up, I realized was a fixed expression.
So, I was wondering it could used in ways like it's been used in the given sentence. Like to say, he was injured in more places than he wasn't.
Would sentences like this be correct: he's achieved **more than not**, like to say he's achieved more than he hasn't?

Comment: While you wouldn't normally see "he's achieved more than not", it isn't even incorrect in my humble opinion.  You just don't usually see it used in that context.  I couldn't really tell you the *why* behind this, so I won't answer.

Comment: As you say, 'more often than not' is a fixed expression. 'More places than not' and 'achieved more than not' just aren't. Indeed, I'm not sure that it really makes sense to say the latter - I'm struggling to think of a context where it might fit.

Comment: @peterG, how about this "He's been to more countries than not.", wouldn't it mean the same as saying He's been to more countries than he hasn't been to?

Comment: "He was injured in more places than not.", isn't it the same as saying he was injured in more places than he wasn't injured in?

Comment: Your two examples would be understood by a native speaker, but would sound awkward and not idiomatic. You mention 'fixed expressions' - for no reason that I or Neil can explain, your two examples just aren't, and would be slightly jarring to a native English speaker.  We would simply use a different form of words to express those concepts eg "He's been to lots of countries", "He's been all over the world"